# Final result of repeatedly adding prime factors of a number and replacing that number by the sum until it repeats

Tags: algorithm, primes, factors

Consider the following operation -- we take a positive integer n and replace it with the sum of its prime factors (if a prime number is presented multiple times in the factorization of n, then it's counted the same number of times in the sum). This operation is applied sequentially first to the given number, than to the first result, than to the second result and so on, until the result remains the same.
Given any number, find the final result of the operation.

Example:
`24 -> (2 + 2 + 2 + 3) = 9 -> (3 + 3) = 6 -> (2 + 3) = 5 -> 5.`

So the answer for 24 is 5.

Other than a brute force solution i could not find a better solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Unless there's a limit on n it belongs to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look [the OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A029908) for this sequence.

It includes a couple of code snippets, for example this one in Maple:

```
f:= proc(n) option remember;
if isprime(n) then n
else `procname`(add(x[1]*x[2], x = ifactors(n)[2]))
fi
end proc:
f(1):= 0: f(4):= 4:
map(f, [$1..100]); # Robert Israel, Apr 27 2015
```

I don't know Maple, but that looks a lot like a recursive definition like the one you're suggesting. I'd therefore be inclined to say that iteration until a prime is reached (excepting special cases for 1 and 4) is the most efficient method of calculation.

There's also a Mathematica script, but it's completely impenetrable to me:

```
ffi[x_] := Flatten[FactorInteger[x]] lf[x_] := Length[FactorInteger[x]] ba[x_] := Table[Part[ffi[x], 2*w-1], {w, 1, lf[x]}] ep[x_] := Table[Part[ffi[x], 2*w], {w, 1, lf[x]}] slog[x_] := slog[x_] := Apply[Plus, ba[x]*ep[x]] Table[FixedPoint[slog, w], {w, 1, 128}]
f[n_] := Plus @@ Flatten[ Table[ #[[1]], {#[[2]]}] & /@ FactorInteger@n]; Array[ FixedPoint[f, # ] &, 87] (* Robert G. Wilson v, Jan 18 2006 *)
fz[n_]:=Plus@@(#[[1]]*#[[2]]&/@FactorInteger@n); Array[FixedPoint[fz, #]&, 1000] (* Zak Seidov, Mar 14 2011 *)
```

[This related sequence](http://oeis.org/A002217) gives the number of iterations required until a result is reached. It says there's only one value of n < 10000 for which more than 10 iterations are required, so it seems a quickly converging algorithm too.